# Loading a test .env file in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run snapshot tests on a react project with jest using a local .env file, but I can't figure out how to get jest to recognize it.

so far I've tried:

- adding `dotenv.config({path: 'path/to/.env'});` in jest.setup.js
- running jest with -env='path/to/.env' in the cli adding
- testEnvironment: 'path/to/.env' in the jest.config.js

is this functionality supported? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you can just do this:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "export $(xargs < .env) && jest",
  ...
}
```

The `export $(xargs < .env)` part loads the environment values from `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

What I currently do is something like this:

```
beforeEach(()=> {
    process.env = Object.assign(process.env, { REACT_APP_ENV_VAR: 'some env variable' });
});
```

In this way, I can choose what variable use on each test, don't forget to clean the `env` on the `afterEach`

Comment: jest loads the env variables correctly for the initial component, however my component has several nested components and these still retain the default env values.

Comment: Unfortunately, if working with API keys, this approach puts it in your test file which is not good. I suppose one could add gibberish, but that could affect other testing.

Answer (score 1):

Place environment variables required by Jest tests in **.env.test**.

See [jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/environment-variables):

```
Jest sets the following environment variables:

NODE_ENV
Set to 'test' if it's not already set to something else.
```

Therefore environment variables in **.env.test** will be set automatically by jest.

Answer (score -1):

`.env` config is for your application and not your tests.

For example, if you want to set different values to a variable in your application based on `env`, it will be something like this

development.env

```
GREET="Hello Dev!"
```

test.env

```
GREET="Hello Master!"
```

production.env

```
GREET="Hello User!"
```

Now your code in the application will be

```
const sendGreeting = () => {
  return process.env.GREET || 'default greet';
};
```

You should run your tests with a script that sets the `NODE_ENV` to `test` in your `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest"
  ...
}
```

So when you test this method in jest, you will have the right value for test env.

```
describe('Test Env', () => {
  it('should return test greeting in test env', () => {
    expect(sendGreetings()).toEqual("Hello Master!");
  });
});
```

Comment: this method didn't work for me. When trying to test environment variables jest returns empty.
I used cross-env NODE_ENV=test, since plain NODE_ENV=test just throws an error

Comment: Why do you need env variables while running tests?

Comment: we have different files (like images) on the website based on user settings such as language etc. I'd like to run snapshot tests for each of the settings by just changing the values in the .env file.